# HTTP request works on browser, fails on everything else

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, connection

### What am I doing

- Two NodeJS/HTTP servers running on ports `3000` and `3001`
- Using Nginx to proxy requests

  - `app.localhost      ->  localhost:3001`
  - `api.app.localhost  ->  localhost:3000`

### What's wrong

Requests perfectly work on browser (Chrome) and return proper status code and JSON data, but fail request fails using `curl` or Postman

**Connection is always refused.**

```
curl http://api.app.localhost/languages
curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.codebottle.localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

### Setup

*Nginx config*

```
server {
    listen          127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name     app.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_set_header                Host codebottle.localhost;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
}

server {
    listen          127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name     api.app.localhost;
    ...
}
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       app.localhost.dev
127.0.0.1       api.app.localhost.dev
```

### What I have tried

- Using `--ipv4` with `curl`
- Making sure that servers, as well as Nginx, are running properly
- Tried setting different headers like `Host`, `Origin`, and `User-Agent`

Comment: I wonder if you can bind to 127.0.0.1:80 with multiple servers - not sure, never tried. Given you've set up domains in host suggest you try binding to domain names. "listen 80; server_name www.example.com;"

Comment: The names you have in `/etc/hosts` do not match the names you are trying to use in your web requests.

Comment: Please show output of `curl -v http://api.app.localhost/languages`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't understand how I even managed to miss the `.dev`. If you can please add an answer so I can mark it as a solution